# UNIX File Descriptors Reuse

Tags: c++, c, unix, file-descriptor

Though I'm reasonably used to UNIX and have programmed on it for a long time, I'm not used to file manipulation.

I know that 0/1/2 file descriptors are standard in, out, and error.  I'm aware that whenever  a process opens a file, it is given a descriptor with the smallest value that isn't yet used - and I understand some things about using dup/dup2.

I get confused about file descriptors between processes though.  Does each process have its own 0/1/2 descriptors for in/out/error or are those 3 descriptors shared between all processes?  How come you can run 3 programs in 3 different shells and they all get only their programs output if they are shared?

If two programs open myfile.txt after start-up, will they both use file descriptor #3, or would the second program use #4 since 3 was taken?

I know I asked the same question in a couple ways there, but I just wanted to be clear.  The more detail the better :) I've never run into problems with these things while programming, but I'm reading through a UNIX book to understand more and I suddenly realized this confused me a lot and I'd never though about it in detail before.

Comment: You'll get better comments if you add a 'c' language tag to your posting. I think I have seen this discussed numerous times, so search for '[c] stdout dup descriptors'. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, added the tags - I'll try looking at the other questions too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each file descriptor is local to the process. However, some file descriptors can refer to the same file - for example, if you create a child process using `fork()` it would share the files opened by the parent. It would have its own set of file descriptors, initially identical to the parent's ones, but they can change with closing/dup-ing, etc.

If two programs open the same file, in general they get separate file descriptors, pointing to separate internal structures. However, using certain techniques (`fork`, FD passing, etc.) you can have file descriptors in different processes point to the same internal entity. Generally, though, it is not the case.

Answering your question, both programs would have FD #3 for newly open file.

Answer (score 3):

File descriptors in Unix (normally) persist through fork() and exec() calls. So yes, several processes can share file descriptors.

For example, a shell might do a command like:

```
foo | bar
```

In this case, foo's stdout must be connected to bar's stdin. To do this, the shell will most likely use pipe() to create reader- and writer file descriptors. It fork()s twice. The descriptors persist. The fork() which will call up foo, will close(1); dup(writer_fd); to make writer_fd descriptor 1. It will then exec(), and process foo will output to the pipe we created. For bar, we close(0); dup(reader); then exec(). And voila, foo will output to bar.

Comment: Processes never share descriptors. However multiple file descriptors (in the same process or different processes) can refer to the same "open file description", which has shared attributes like current position, nonblocking flag, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Don't confuse the file descriptors with the resources they represent. You can have ten different processes, each with a file descriptor of '3' open, and each refer to a different open file. When a process does I/O using its file descriptor, the OS knows which process is doing the I/O and is able to disambiguate which file is being referred to.